# Why does adding android.support.v7.app as library to my project fail?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am trying to use the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in my project. For that I have added `android-support-v7-appcompat` to my project. When I reference it, there's a green tick mark. But when, after closing the properties of my project, I reopen them, I got a red cross. How can I fix that?

I have also copied the *appcompat* folder into my current workspace.

[image: Properties page]

Comment: You have to compile with api 21 or 23. It depends by which appcompat you are using. And switch to Android Studio!

Comment: what does that mean? "compiling"... i haven't compiled it yet.

Comment: You have to set which level of API to use to compile your project. https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.imbifcnqo